# How does a CassandraRepository get assigned connection configurations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring data Cassandra and have two different Cassandra configurations. Each of them are getting assigned a different key space and user/password. I also have two different Repositories that should use their specific config. Sometimes each repository uses the correct config, but sometimes they do not. How do I “assign” the config class to the proper repository?

Comment: How do you currently setup the repositories and their config? Are the repos in different packages?

Comment: I have created two different classes extending AbstractCassandraConfig each of which include Configuration, Lazy, EnableCassandraRepositories (basePackages value is pointing to where repo is for the config) annotations. In one configuration class I override cluster(), session(), etc. Then in the repositories I just extend CassandraRepository and include Query annotation for the methods to access the DB. They are in different packages. Let me know if more info is required...

Comment: Should I maybe include the config classes in the same package as the associated repository?